# Recover a particular folder from the hard disk

Tags: external-hard-drive, data-recovery

I am learning about recovery processes of corrupted / deleted data etc. from hard disks. So, I took an external hard disk and made 3 big folders with Pictures Videos and Music. The total data content is around 25 GB on a hard disk of around 1 TB.
Then I went on to dd this hard disk with 0 but only the the first 200MB.
Ofcourse, I cannot see the data on the hard disk anymore. 
Is there a way I can recover the folder for example Video from the hard disk. 
The data in the hard disk is absolutely dummy, and hence any suggestion that might worsen the situation is also fine. Help would be grateful.

I want to know here what exactly hapenned in this case, when I swiped off the first 200 MB of the hard disk? How does the recovery tool actually work when they dont see a partition table etc.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04  as my operating system and the external hard disk is formatted with NTFS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover lost/inacessible data from my storage device?](http://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inacessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Comment: Well actually, I was more concerned about the technical details. I mean what hapenned here, when I swiped off the first 200 MB of the hard disk? How does the recovery tool actually work when they dont see a partition table etc. I have edited the question so that is is clearer.